# Can't install Minecraft on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, java, 18.04, minecraft

I've been perplexed by this Java issue for about 4 days now. I recently upgraded to Kubuntu 18.04 and am trying to get Minecraft to work to no avail. Here are my error messages:

```
nathan@Corbit:~/Minecraft$ sudo java -jar Minecraft.jar                        
Bootstrap (v5)
Current time is May 10, 2018 7:05:05 AM
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Linux'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '4.15.0-21-generic'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.8.0_171'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'`

`Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 2/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 3/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 4/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 5/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 6/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 7/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 8/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 9/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 10/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Unable to download remote file. Check your internet connection/proxy settings.
FATAL ERROR: net.minecraft.bootstrap.FatalBootstrapError: Unable to download while being forced
        at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.execute(Bootstrap.java:95)
        at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:381)
```

I've tried updating my certificates, verified that port 25565 is open, made an exception for said port in UFW even though I have it disabled, used several versions of OPENjdk and Oracle, Used several different archived versions of Minecraft.jar, tried running as root (as you can see), but I have gotten nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, and it was resolved with the following command:

```
sudo snap install minecraft
```

To start Minecraft run the following command:

```
minecraft
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem in kubuntu 18.04 I did:

```
sudo rm /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

and then:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

(Don't run java with `sudo`)